# Chef overwrite default attributes of a cookbook

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

The git cookbook has an error in the url that it uses to download the appropriate version. The url is set in the attributes file as a default attribute so I figured I could just overwrite the url with something static but it does not work.  Here is the code from the git cookbook:

```
case node['platform_family']
when 'windows'
  default['git']['version'] = '2.8.1'
  if node['kernel']['machine'] == 'x86_64'
    default['git']['architecture'] = '64'
    default['git']['checksum'] = '5e5283990cc91d1e9bd0858f8411e7d0afb70ce26e23680252fb4869288c7cfb'
  else
    default['git']['architecture'] = '32'
default['git']['checksum'] = '17418c2e507243b9c98db161e9e5e8041d958b93ce6078530569b8edaec6b8a4'
  end
  default['git']['url'] = 'https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v%{version}.windows.1/Git-%{version}-%{architecture}-bit.exe'
```

The cookbook is being included as a dependency in my metadata.rb file and used as a resource in my recipe. It is not part of the runlist. I've tried overwriting the url in my role file like so

```
"name": "web",
  "description": "Web Server Role.",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "default_attributes": {
    "chef_client": {
      "interval": 300,
      "splay": 60
    },
    "git": {
      "url": "a test string"
    }
  },...
```

That did not work, so I tried adding it to the attributes file of my recipe as a default value, and when that did not work, I tried the `override!` method which still did not work.

I think the problem is due to the fact that the attribute does not exist when I have declared it, and it gets overwritten by the git recipe.

I don't know how to get around that.

Comment: Did you try to put ``default['git']['url'] in attributes/default.rb in your recipe folder?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work here is what it looks like currently `override!['git']['url'] = 'test string'`

Answer (score 2):

Use `override_attributes` instead of `default_attributes`:

```
"name": "web",
"description": "Web Server Role.",
"json_class": "Chef::Role",
"default_attributes": {
  "chef_client": {
    "interval": 300,
    "splay": 60
  }
},
"override_attributes": {
  "git": {
    "url": "a test string"
  }
},...
```